# Making Vapor API response JSON API Spec compliant

Tags: swift, generics, vapor

I have an API, written in Vapor. I would like to follow the JSON API Spec.

I am struggling with understanding how I can create my response object in the correct format.

For example, I would like my responses to be structured as so...

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/dish",
    "next": "http://example.com/dish?page=2",
    "last": "http://example.com/dish?page=10"
  },
  "data": [{
    "title": "Spag Bol",
    "course": "main",
    "description": "BasGetti",
    "price": 3.9900000000000002
  },
  {
    "title": "Ice Cream",
    "course": "desert",
    "description": "Vanilla",
    "price": 0.98999999999999999
  }]
}
```

I can return the contents of data quite simply if `POST` to this endpoint (pseudo code)

```
router.post(Dish.self, at: "api/dish") { req, data -> Future<Dish> in
    return Future.map(on: req, { () -> Dish in
        data.id = 001
        return data
    })
}
```

I tried creating an `ApiResponse` class and passing in the data so I could structure the response but this did not work with the error `Cannot convert return expression of type 'ApiResonse' to return type 'Dish'`

```
   router.post(Dish.self, at: "api/dish") { req, data -> Future<Dish> in
        return Future.map(on: req, { () -> Dish in
            data.id = 001
            return ApiResonse(links: Links(self: "http://google.com", next: "http://google.com", last: "http://google.com"), data: data)
        })
    }
```

I am not sure how I can do this. These are the attempted classes

```
final class Dish: Content {
    var id: Int?
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var course: String
    var price: Double

    init(title: String, description: String, course: String, price: Double) {
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.course = course
        self.price = price
    }
}

struct Links {
    var `self`: String?
    var next: String?
    var last: String?
}

class ApiResonse {
    var links: Links?
    var data: Any

    init(links: Links, data: Any) {
        self.links = links
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Do I need to use Generics to set up the response class? Is anyone able to provide an example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Each `class` or `struct` in the compound object `ApiResponse` needs to comply with the `Content` protocol. The `Content` protocol includes the `Codable` protocol for JSON decoding and encoding.
2. Note that `Any` *does not* comply with the `Codable` protocol, and therefore `Any` *can not* be used as any component part of a Response.  See [Vapor 3 Docs: "Using Content"](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/vapor/content/) and [Vapor 4 Docs: "Content"](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/content/) for more detailed information.

   > Vapor 3: all content types (JSON, protobuf, URLEncodedForm, Multipart, etc) are treated the same. All you need to parse and serialize content is a `Codable` class or struct.

   > Vapor 4: Vapor's content API allows you to easily encode / decode `Codable` structs to / from HTTP messages.
3. An object or compound object which fully complies with `Content` can be used as a `ResponseEncodable` response.
4. The `ApiResponse` model can be *generic* when each *route endpoint resolves to a specific `Content` protocol compliant type*.

*An example project with the code below is on [GitHub: VaporExamplesLab/Example-SO-VaporJsonResponse](https://github.com/VaporExamplesLab/Example-SO-VaporJsonResponse).*

**Example Models**

```
struct Dish: Content {
    var id: Int?
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var course: String
    var price: Double
    
    init(id: Int? = nil, title: String, description: String, course: String, price: Double) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.course = course
        self.price = price
    }
}

struct Links: Content {
    var current: String?
    var next: String?
    var last: String?
}

struct ApiResponse: Content {
    var links: Links?
    var dishes: [Dish]
    
    init(links: Links, dishes: [Dish]) {
        self.links = links
        self.dishes = dishes
    }
}
```

**Example `POST`: Returns `ApiResponse`**

```
router.post(Dish.self, at: "api/dish") { 
    (request: Request, dish: Dish) -> ApiResponse in
    var dishMutable = dish
    dishMutable.id = 001
    
    var links = Links()
    links.current = "http://example.com"
    links.next = "http://example.com"
    links.last = "http://example.com"

    return ApiResponse(links: links, dishes: [dishMutable])
}
```

**Example `POST`: Returns `Future<ApiResponse>`**

```
router.post(Dish.self, at: "api/dish-future") { 
    (request: Request, dish: Dish) -> Future<ApiResponse> in
    var dishMutable = dish
    dishMutable.id = 002
    
    var links = Links()
    links.current = "http://example.com"
    links.next = "http://example.com"
    links.last = "http://example.com"
    
    return Future.map(on: request, { 
        () -> ApiResponse in
        return ApiResponse(links: links, dishes: [dishMutable])
    }) 
}
```

**JSON Response Received**

The Response body for the above code produces the following:

```
{
  "links": {
    "current": "http://example.com",
    "next": "http://example.com",
    "last": "http://example.com"
  },
  "dishes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Aztec Salad",
      "description": "Flavorful Southwestern ethos with sweet potatos and black beans.",
      "course": "salad",
      "price": 1.82
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Generic Model**

```
struct ApiResponseGeneric<T> : Content where T: Content { 
    var links: Links?
    var data: T
    
    init(links: Links, data: T) {
        self.links = links
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

**Concrete Route Endpoint**

```
router.post(Dish.self, at: "api/dish-generic-future") { 
    (request: Request, dish: Dish) -> Future<ApiResponseGeneric<[Dish]>> in
    var dishMutable = dish
    dishMutable.id = 004
    
    var links = Links()
    links.current = "http://example.com"
    links.next = "http://example.com"
    links.last = "http://example.com"
    
    return Future.map(on: request, { 
        () -> ApiResponseGeneric<[Dish]> in
        return ApiResponseGeneric<[Dish]>(links: links, data: [dishMutable])
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. For the time you put into this and the provided repo, I wish I could upvote an answer many, many times!

Comment: Is it possible to use ApiResponse with multiple types? Say for example I had a Dish response and also on another endpoint a Menu response? Could I share APIResponse or what I need to create a new version of it each time?

Comment: @pgGriff An example for how `ApiResponse` can be used with generics has been added to the answer.

Comment: I am lost for words how helpful you have been. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `data` be `[Dish]`

```
class ApiResonse {
    var links: Links?
    var data: [Dish]

    init(links: Links, data: [Dish]) {
        self.links = links
        self.data = [Dish]
    }
}
```